# how to stop background 30px from bottom

Tags: css

I have a background image to blockquote but i want it to stop 30px or so from the bottom of the blockquote.

current css:

```
.project-inner-quotes blockquote
{
  background: url("Img/quoteTop.gif") no-repeat scroll center top transparent  ;
  margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

the reason is I have a p tag in the quote which has the closing speech buuble...

```
.project-inner-quotes blockquote > p:last-child 
{
    background: url("Img/quoteBot.gif") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    padding: 30px 20px 50px 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that can be "faked" with css in a tricky way because it depends on your design. I will make some assumptions now, first of all your blockquote container element has a #fff background (could be any color really).

in that case you could do this:

```
.project-inner-quotes blockquote > p:last-child {
    background: url("Img/white-image_8x30") repeat-x scroll left bottom transparent;
}

.project-inner-quotes blockquote > p:last-child span {
    background: url("Img/quoteBot.gif") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    padding: 30px 20px 50px 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

this will "fake" a 30px offset from the bottom. wrap your p text inside the span that will get the background image and display block to get the padding applied.

you will need to create a 8px wide (for better tiling) and 30px high image that will be applied to the paragraph at the bottom. the color of the image will be the color of the background you are trying to get when "offsetting" the quoteTop image... however this approach will fail if you do not have a solid color as main background.

let me know if it's not clear